# Allocating memory to a 3-dimensional char array causes segmentation fault

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, char, malloc

As a spin of of an earlier question, I have run into some problems regarding allocating memory to a 3 dimensional array.

I am working on a project where we need to do some work on a text. To do this, we need to split the text into smaller sections, and process the text word for word. To save these smaller pieces of text, we have a 3D array, a list of sections each containing a list of the words in the section.

But I get a segmentation fault when I try to allocate memory for the individual words using `malloc()`.

```
localText->list[i][n] = malloc(100 * sizeof(char));
```

Here is the entire code.

```
typedef struct {
   char name[100];
   char  ***list;
}text;

int main(){
   int i = 0, n, z,wordCount, sections;
   FILE *file;
   text *localText;

   openFile(&file, "test.txt");
   wordCount = countWords(file);

   sections = (wordCount / 50) + 1;

   localText = malloc(sizeof(text));
   localText->list = malloc(sections * sizeof(char **));

   for(i = 0; i < sections; i++)
      localText->list[i] = malloc(50 * sizeof(char *));
      for(n = 0; n < 50; n++)
         localText->list[i][n] = malloc(100 * sizeof(char));

   readFileContent(file, localText->list, 50);

   freeText(localText);

   return 1;
}
```

Comment: W/o braces only one statement belongs to the loop body. Don't ever leave out braces! :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're missing some braces:

```
for(i = 0; i < sections; i++) {
// ...
}
```

Comment: Yet another reason for always bracing constructs, even if they are only 1 line.

Comment: Well i thank you very much, laziness is indeed to root to all evil;)